# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am doing a GET request via postman to access a company through
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/company /1

Just added a method in the companies controller as this:

```
module Api 
  module V1
    class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
      def index 
        @companies = Company.order('created_at DESC');
        render json: { status: 'SUCCESS', message:'Loaded companies', data:@companies }, status: :ok
      end

      def show 
        @companies = Company.find(params[:id])
        render json: { status: 'SUCCESS', message:'Loaded company', data:@companies }, status: :ok 
      end
    end 
  end 
end
```

My logs look like this:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
    Started GET "/api/v1/companies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-28 08:20:43 +0300
   (1.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by Api::V1::CompaniesController#index as */*
  Company Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  Company Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 143ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



  Company Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
NameError (undefined local variable or method `companies' for #<Api::V1::CompaniesController:0x000000043ff3c8>
Did you mean?  @companies):

app/controllers/api/v1/companies_controller.rb:6:in `index'
  Company Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
    Started GET "/api/v1/companies" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-28 08:21:04 +0300
Processing by Api::V1::CompaniesController#index as */*
  Company Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY created_at DESC
Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 19.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)


Started GET "/api/v1/companies%20/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-28 08:33:41 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/companies%20/1"):

actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:93:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/api/v1/companies%20/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-28 08:34:46 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/companies%20/1"):

actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:93:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/api/v1/companies%20/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-28 08:35:53 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/companies%20/1"):

actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:93:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/api/v1/company%20/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-28 08:35:58 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/company%20/1"):

actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:93:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/api/v1/company%20/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-28 08:36:25 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/company%20/1"):

actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:93:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/api/v1/company%20/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-28 08:36:37 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/company%20/1"):

actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:93:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
Started GET "/api/v1/company%20/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-28 08:37:03 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/v1/company%20/1"):

actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.1.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
rack-cors (1.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:93:in `call'
railties (5.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:605:in `handle_request'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:437:in `process_client'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/server.rb:301:in `block in run'
puma (3.10.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Can you add your routes and the your Postman request?

Answer (score 0):

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/api/v1/companies%20/1"):

Your route has a **space** after `companies` which resulted in that error. Make sure your route doesn't contain the space. It should look like

```
"/api/v1/companies/1"
```